# Инверсия Фильтрации объектов на Яндекс карте (ObjectManager, setFilter)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, пожалуйста,  в примере https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_filter показана фильтрация объектов.

В чем заключается не удобство и мой вопрос.

Например, чтобы показать только 'Школы' мне нужно снять остальные галочки ('Аптека', 'Магазин', 'Больница', 'Бар'), это не удобно, как сделать наоборот, чтобы поставив галочку отобразились соответствующие объекты?

В примере есть код:

```
...
// Создадим 5 пунктов выпадающего списка.
    var listBoxItems = ['Школа', 'Аптека', 'Магазин', 'Больница', 'Бар']
            .map(function (title) {
                return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
                    data: {
                        content: title
                    },
                    state: {
                        selected: true
                    }
                })
            }),
...
```

если **state: selected: true** заменить на **false**, получается то, что нужно, но когда все галочки сняты на карте нет ни одного объекта, я понимаю, что метод isSelected в этот момент возвращает false. Не хватает метода isDeselected, чтобы было наоборот.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы когда галочки все сняты (deselect), показать все объекты на карте, если можно на примере песочныцы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно проверить, что не выбранно ни одного типа меток:

```
function getFilterFunction(categories) {
    var isCategoriesEmpty = Object.values(categories).reduce(function(acc, value) {return acc || value}, false);
    return function (obj) {
        var content = obj.properties.balloonContent;
        return !isCategoriesEmpty || categories[content]
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kqc6epx9/

Comment: Большое спасибо! Это то, что нужно.